Python: Split Polygons where they overlap one another
I have a python script that produces a shapefile of polygons, created primarily using geopandas.
I wish to split polygons where they overlap each other. Ideally removing all but one feature where overlaps are found by maintaining the feature with the smallest value/ latest date etc. The exact requirement will vary.
I have been experimenting with overlays in the geopandas module, iterating through each feature in the geodataframe. However, I am not getting the results I require.
I can easily perform this action in FME or ESRI, but would ideally like to include this process as part of the larger script and not require the need to maintain software licenses so I am looking for an open source solution.

For example, in the above image I am trying to split the three features into 12, and then to the 7 by removing the features with the lower value information.

You can use unary_union, polygonize, and drop_duplicates or groupby (not sure what you want to do):
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import unary_union, polygonize

#Create a df with three overlapping circles 
#  where each circle have a different value in the "value" column
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data={"value":[4,5,6]}, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(x=[1,2,1.5], y=[2,2,1]))
df["geometry"] = df.buffer(distance=1)

bound = unary_union(df.geometry.boundary)

# Bound is a multilinestring looking like this:


polygons = list(polygonize(bound)) #Create polygons from it
polydf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=polygons) #And a dataframe

#Intersect it with the original dataframe. This will create duplicate polygons 
#  where there are overlaps
inter = gpd.overlay(df, polydf, how="intersection", keep_geom_type=True)

#Even though there are duplicate geometries, geopandas doesnt recognize them by their geometries:
#inter.geometry.duplicated().any()
#False

#But it will find them by a combination of their area and centroid coords:
def givegrouper(row):
    """Function to return a string of rounded area, and centroid coordinates
    Example: 0.656 1.5 2.31393 """
    area = round(row.geometry.area, 3)
    c = row.geometry.centroid
    cent_x = round(c.x, 5)
    cent_y = round(c.y, 5)
    return f"{area} {cent_x} {cent_y}"

inter["groupby_string"] = inter.apply(lambda x: givegrouper(x), axis=1)
# inter.groupby_string.duplicated().any()
# True

#So it is now possible to either groupby or drop duplicates by groupby_string.
inter = inter.sort_values(by=["groupby_string", "value"], ascending=True) #Sort from low to high values
inter = inter.drop_duplicates(subset="groupby_string", keep="first") #Drop duplicate geometries, keep first which is lowest

#There are some slivers with very small areas created in the processing, drop them
inter = inter.loc[inter.area>1e-5]

The lowest values are kept where there were overlaps in the geometries, and the geometries do not longer overlap:

You might want to dissolve to merge all adjacent polygons with the same value.
